Not able to SSH and EC2 Instance Connect with the EC2 instance
I'm experiencing recurring issues with SSH connectivity to my EC2 instance. I’m unable to SSH into the instance using both the PEM file and EC2 Instance Connect.
The error message for EC2 Instance Connect is:

"EC2 Instance Connect is unable to connect to your instance. Ensure
your instance network settings are configured correctly for EC2
Instance Connect. For more information, see EC2 Instance Connect
Prerequisites."

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified that the instance network settings are correct and security groups allows ssh port. But still the issue persists.
Restarted the instance, which temporarily resolves the issue.
Question:
I am looking for an explanation of why this issue occurs frequently and what might be causing it. Are there common reasons for EC2 Instance Connect and PEM file-based SSH failures, and how can I address these to prevent recurring issues? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I also think this issue might be related to AWS. I could be mistaken.
Here is the error message:


Are you saying the connectivity works after a reboot, but later does not work? If so, the problem would lie within the EC2 instance itself. It is possible that some software is consuming all the CPU or a network setting is temporarily changed. You can use the Monitoring tab to see if the CPU Utilization is very high.

check your region I am doubtful about it, i have faced it often

@AshishKamble I was using Mumbai Region(ap-south-1)
What need to check there?
